# Is there a ready-made component to transform java *.properties file into corresponding json?

Tags: java, json, serialization, properties

I suppose it's not hard to write one, but I'm just wondering is there something ready-made, that could fix this task in one line and with no additional coding?

It's especially helpful if you want to keep some configuration in *.properties file and with no intermediate models put it in json format.

Comment: What I already found is that I can easily transform nested map to json with [jackson](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes#A.22Raw.22_Data_Binding_Example). But I still need to transform Properties object into maps.  E.g. **a.b.c=4** into nested map (a->(b->(c->4))).

Comment: It turns out there is such library - https://github.com/nzakas/props2js - however I didn't test it yet.

Answer (score 0):

I found a git with Json to other formats and vice versa. You can check this pull request which added java property to JSON to this project.

https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-java/pull/82